# Creating shapes in an SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, raphael

For my assignment, we create an SVG block and the user would input a number, and we add that number of squares to the svg block in random positions within the svg block. My code isn't working.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/raphael-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>Exercise 10</title>
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Exercise 10</h1>

<div id="svg1"></div>

<div class="form">Add how many?
<input type="text" id="howmany" />
<button id="more">Add More</button></div>

<div id="svg2"></div>

<div class="form">
<button id="another">Add Another</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
var num_squares, x, y;
num_squares = $('#howmany').val()
add_more = function() {

    for (count = 0;count < num_squares;count += 1)
    {
        x = Math.random() * 180
        y = Math.random() * 180
        r = paper.rect(x, y, 20, 20)
        filled = {
          'fill': '#ddf'
        }
        r.attr(filled)
    }
}

setup = function() {
  paper = Raphael('svg1', 200, 200)
    add_more()
}
jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#svg1 {
    border: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialise num_squares outside the function i.e. on document load. This is before anyone's typed in a number so num_squares is always empty and therefore your loop doesn't do anything. You also aren't calling add_more when the button is pressed.

```js
add_more = function() {

    var num_squares, x, y;
    num_squares = $('#howmany').val();
    for (count = 0;count < num_squares;count += 1)
    {
        x = Math.random() * 180
        y = Math.random() * 180
        r = paper.rect(x, y, 20, 20)
        filled = {
          'fill': '#ddf'
        }
        r.attr(filled)
    }
}

setup = function() {
  paper = Raphael('svg1', 200, 200)
}
jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```

```css
#svg1 {
    border: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/raphael-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>Exercise 10</title>
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Exercise 10</h1>

<div id="svg1"></div>

<div class="form">Add how many?
<input type="text" id="howmany">
<button id="more" onclick="add_more()">Add More</button></div>

<div id="svg2"></div>

<div class="form">
<button id="another">Add Another</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I said in the first paragraph of the answer.